# Wifi Hotspot in Ubuntu for wireless network

Tags: wireless, hot-spot

So I searched a lot but couldn't find a solution to share my wireless network via Hotspot for Ubuntu. On the same device, Windows 10 can do it but I need a solution for Ubuntu 18.04 as I can't really switch to Windows just for this.

Comment: I might be wrong but I don’t think that you can be connected to a wireless network and host a wireless hotspot at the same time unless you have 2 wireless network cards- 1 connected to the network and one to host the hotspot for other devices to connect to. You could also connect the computer to Ethernet and then use the free wireless network card for the hotspot but again, I’m not sure if this is true or not.

Comment: Do you wish to receive an internet connection from a phone or hotspot, or do you wish to use your Ubuntu machine to become a hotspot? Different solutions.

Comment: My query is just that if it's possible on Windows, it should be possible on Ubuntu as well on the same laptop, right?